# Vue.js: Get data from "parent" Vue

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

I have an (unchangeable) DOM structure as followed:

```
<div id="indexVue">
  ...
  <div id="childVue">
  ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

And two js files:

index.js:

```
var child = require('childVue');

module.exports = new Vue({
  el: '#indexVue',
  ...
});
```

childVue.js:

```
module.exports = new Vue({
  el: '#childVue',
  methods: {
    something: function(){
      // Parent data needed here ...
    },
    ...
  }
});
```

As shown, I need the data of the `indexVue` in `childVue`. Is there any way to pass it to it? I tried to pass it to a function with `(v-on="click: childFunction($data)")`, but that only (logically) returns the data attribute from the `childVue` and not from the `indexVue`.

Google does not really help, as Vue is not well-documented.

The real file and DOM structure are way bigger and more complicated, but necessary for my problem are only these files.

Also I am not allowed to use jQuery here, which would make it a task of seconds.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer from Pantelis is not true anymore. Vue.js  removed the inherit property.

The best way to do that is to [pass data through properties;](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props)

```
<div id="indexVue">
  <child-vue :some-data="someData"></child-vue>
</div>
```

index.js:

```
module.exports = new Vue({
  el: '#indexVue',
  data: {
    someData: "parent's data"
  },
  components: {
    childVue: require('childVue')
  }
});
```

childVue.js:

```
module.exports = {
  template: '<div>{{someData}}</div>',
  methods: {
    something: function(){
      // you can access the parent's data
      console.log(this.someData)
    }
  },
  props: ['some-data'] // kebab case here available as camelcase in template
};
```

Please note the `props` property in `childVue.js` and the case ([camelCase vs kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case)) used for the property name

Comment: Great answer. You also aren't required to put the `:` before the prop for the child component either. The camelCasing verse the kebab-casing is important to highlight like you did!

Comment: @creedjarrett colon depends if it is dynamic prop or not so it can be necessary

Comment: @JaroslavKlimčík i actually just ran into this issue, and you are right. for dynamic props you need the `:`. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

You could also access it by this.$parent.someData in case you cannot bind it on a prop :) for example:

```
data() {
 return {
  parentData: this.$parent.someData
 }
}
```

Comment: This is the most clean way to do it IMHO.

Comment: Don't ever use this in production because you have no idea where the property is inherited from in the parent chain so you just made the component less reusable. I still +1'd this because I'm prototyping some stuff and this workaround helped me.

Comment: @A1rPun, What do you mean by "just made the component less resusable."?
As I used the answers its works for me. Is there something I could be worried for?

Comment: @MONSTEEEER If your component relies on parent variables to be set the design is flawed because what happens when you place said component in another parent or even in someone else's project? You can't assume the variables to be set and there is also the issue about having multiple parents so from which parent are you getting your data from? These questions raise suspicion in intent so this solution needs to be avoided.

Comment: Oohh. Nice, I got your point. In this case, do you have any solution to it? @A1rPun

Comment: @MONSTEEEER The accepted solution on this page :) so passing data down and emitting events up.

Comment: Still in terms of design sometimes you just want to create a component for code segmentation and keep business together. I personally think it all depends what you want to acheive.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a `child component` to [inherit](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Inheriting_Parent_Scope) the scope of its parent.

index.html

```
<div id="indexVue">
  <child-vue></child-vue>
</div>
```

index.js:

```
module.exports = new Vue({
  el: '#indexVue',
  data: {
    someData: "parent's data"
  },
  components: {
    childVue: require('childVue')
  }
});
```

childVue.js:

```
module.exports = {
  inherit: true,
  template: '<div>...</div>',
  methods: {
    something: function(){
      // you can access the parent's data
      console.log(this.someData)
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it _will_ break if/when you upgrade to Vue 1.0.* From [Vue.js Github Release Notes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases): "The inherit option has been deprecated. Always pass data to child components via props."